# Calculating the number of interrupts within 1 sec from process context

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, irq

I Have a requirement where I need to calculate number of interrupts that occurs within 1 sec.
I'm planning to have below approach

**Process Context:**

```
atomic_set(&irq_enblflg, 1);
//enable IRQ flg and sleep for 1 sec.
mdelay(1000);//maybe we can look for altenative later on
atomic_set(&irq_enblflg, 0);
```

**Interrupt Context:**

```
static irqreturn_t tach_isr(int irq, void *d)
{
        //printk(KERN_CRIT "ISR#########\n");
        if (atomic_read(&irq_enblflg)) {
            pulse++;
        }
        return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

I will enable `irq_enblflg` and sleep for 1 sec from process context whenever I want to calculate the number of pulses.

Can someone please comment whether sleeping in process context is proper approach for calculating number of interrupts within sec or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends if the implementation of `atomic_read` will pause your interrupt code waiting for the availability of the shared variable.  If that happens, you'll end with a lock in your interrupt code and the interrupts disabled, that's dangerous.

In general, if you disable interrupts in a code block, there's no chance that the associated interrupt will occur in that shared region, so it's normally fine just to disable interrupts, access the shared data, then reenable interrupts.  In the interrupt code you don't need to do anything, as the interrupt cannot occur in the middle of the shared blocking code, so you only need to check the value of the shared variable, as you are executing interrupt code, so there's no chance that a new interrupt comes and modifies the variable (thing that does not happen in the interrupt code)

It's bad idea to block an interrupt handler, you can only do this for example in FreeBSD, where interrupt handlers run with a context (as a process) or when you have some means of a spinlock (busy waiting, in a loop) so you can wait, but without leaving the context as the interrupts normally run in the context of the process they interrupt.

Comment: thanks for reply, can you please elaborate on this statement **atomic_read will pause your interrupt code waiting for the availability of the shared variable**.What do you mean by availability of shared  variable?.

Comment: I enable **irq_enblflg** and do **sleep** for 1 sec in process context, so that i can count number of interrupts within 1 sec, i was little reluctant to make process context sleep, is it ok to make process context sleep or is there any better way to achieve this?